# ANTLR4 -> Check a literal is STRING_LITERAL or a NUMBER_LITERAL

Tags: java, antlr

Currently, I'm using this ANTLR4 grammar (part of) in order to get `strings` and `numbers`:

Go figure this summarized grammar:

```
gramm
 : expr SCOL
 ;

expr
 : literal          #LiteralExpression
 ;

literal
 : NUMERIC_LITERAL
 | STRING_LITERAL
 ;

NUMERIC_LITERAL
 : DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT* )? ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )?
 | '.' DIGIT+ ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )?
 ;

STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

So, I'm implementing an `GrammBaseVisitor<Void>`.

I'm not quite to figure out how to check whether a literal is a `NUMERIC_LITERAL` or a `STRING_LITERAL`.

As far I've been able to get, I've override `visitLiteral()` and `visitLiteralExpression()`:

```
@Override
public Void visitLiteral(LiteralContext ctx) {
    // TODO What should I do here in order to check whether
    // ctx contains an STRING_LITERAL or a NUMBER_LITERAL?
    return super.visitLiteral(ctx);
}

@Override
public Void visitLiteralExpression(LiteralExpressionContext ctx) {
    return super.visitLiteralExpression(ctx);
}
```

What's the difference between `visitLiteral` and `visitLiteralExpression()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `literal` production consists of two possible terminals, the numeric and string literal. Whether parsed input contains one or the other, you can determine with `null` checks inside `visitLiteral`.

```
@Override
public Object visitLiteral(LiteralContext ctx) {            
    TerminalNode numeric = ctx.NUMERIC_LITERAL();
    TerminalNode string = ctx.STRING_LITERAL();
    if (numeric != null) {
        System.out.println(numeric.getSymbol().getType());
    } else if (string != null) {
        System.out.println(string.getSymbol().getType());
    }
    return super.visitLiteral(ctx);
}
```

You can visit all terminals by overriding `visitTerminal`.

```
@Override
public Object visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
    int type = node.getSymbol().getType(); // matches a constant in your parser

    switch (type) {
        case GrammParser.NUMERIC_LITERAL:
            System.out.println("numeric literal");
            break;
        case GrammParser.STRING_LITERAL:
            System.out.println("string literal");
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(node.getSymbol().getText());
    return super.visitTerminal(node); 
}
```

> What's the difference between visitLiteral and visitLiteralExpression()?

The former represents your `literal` production and the latter represents your `expr` production. Note that `#` symbol has special meaning in ANTLR 4 syntax, representing a label - a name for alternatives inside productions. It is not a comment. Since your `expr` only has one alternative, it becomes `visitLiteralExpression`. Try commenting it out (`//`) and see your generated code change.